# Laravel enable route for only the current user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I have two user types admin and member. Now, members cannot view other profiles except their own. Only admins have access to all user profiles.

Now my route for the UsersController@show (only accessible by admins) is `http://laravel.test/user/username`

However if a user accesses that url with his own username, it should grant the request.

This applies to all other functions such as edit and update.

Now I could create another controller designated for the current user only, call it MyController. I could copy the code from the UsersController, just changing a few codes so that it gets the current user from auth(). But I would prefer not to.

Any help?

Comment: You may want to look at Laravel's [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)  to handle this.  Then protect the routes you need to by add the middleware to those routes.

Comment: show your users table structure , and 1 sample record for admin and users

Comment: Middleware is 100% the way to go.

Comment: @MarcM. could you show me a snippet of this would be done, or at least link to a resource, I've been browsing the internet for hours, no luck.

Comment: @GerardBalaoro  - here's the link with a complete walk through:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Answer (score 0):

if you have your own conditions you should a little change this but logic is this

```
public function show($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username',$username)->get();
    if($user->id == Auth::id()){
        // show profile
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not my ideal solution for it requires me to enclose all statements inside the show, edit, update functions inside that if statement.